# Retractions of Maps

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm being asked to prove that $f:X\longrightarrow X$ is a retraction $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f\circ f=f$ and $f(X)=A$ for some $A\subseteq X$. I'm given the definition of retraction as a map that when $f$ is restricted $A$, the map becomes the canonical inclusion map of that subset i.e. $f|_{A}:A\longrightarrow X$ where $x\longmapsto x$ for $x\in A$.

If $A=X$, I can see how this would work, but if $A\subset X$, the only way I could see this working is if we can assume that because $f|_{A}:A\longrightarrow X$ where $x\longmapsto x$ for $x\in A$ we can assume $f:X\longrightarrow X$ where $x\longmapsto x$ which would imply that $f=id_{X}$. Is this wrong to assume?

Also, please do not prove this for me.

Thank you

Comment: I retracted my first question because I had figured it out before I checked to see if anyone had answered it. The last question I asked the only person to respond didn't even answer the question  I asked, so why would I accept that answer?

Comment: I don't get the definition of retraction. You didn't quantify over $A$. If $A$ is quantified existentially, then the statement is false. If $A$ is quantified universally, then $f$ is the identify map and the statement has no interest.

Comment: No need for $f$ to be the identity mapping. Consider $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $A=\{1,2\}$ and $f$ like $f(1)=1, f(2)=2, f(3)=2$.